# Start Stop thread from class

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to start / stop a thread in order not to block the UI using button

```
public partial class Program_Form : Form
{
    readonly BackgroundWorker m_oWorker;

    [STAThread]
    private void Program_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // long code here 
    }

    private async void DGW6BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Work.Printer_ Print = new Work.Printer_();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Print.Print_File(this, dataGridView6, StatusText, progressBar1,
                variablesStatus);
        });
    }

    public void BTN6PPauza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //What i had tried 
        //_canceller.Dispose();
        //_canceller.Cancel();
        // variablesStatus = false;
        //thread2.break;
        //autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        //thread2.Join();
        //_manualResetEvent.Reset();
        //thread2.Abort();
        //_pauseEvent.Reset();
        //variablesStatus = "Pause";
        //Print_Actions();
    }
}
```

Referenced class:

```
namespace OfficeTools.Work
{
    class Printer_
    {
        public void Print_File(Program_Form callForm, DataGridView DGW,
            TextBox Status, ProgressBar Progress, bool variablesStatus)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in DGW.Rows)
            {
                file = DGW.Rows[Row.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                PrintFiles.Print_Word(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I start stop pause resume the thread because nothing worked from what I had tried, I think the problem is from the `foreach` loop
I never used threads, and I can not find an example similar with mine in order to understand how should I do.

Comment: Why would you pause the thread?

Comment: this thread is printing files around 900 pages. (pdf, doc etc.), i want to pause it in order to refill the printer with paper, etc.

Comment: You cannot access (nor update or create) any UI control on a thread other than the UI thread.  You have to copy the data from the controls ***before*** you call `Print_File`. Other than that, what you're doing looks fine.

Comment: @StoicaVasile - Why pause it? Let it print out entirely and that should work. When you reload paper the printer should continue printing fine. Does it not?

Comment: @Enigmativity i have multiple reasons that i whant to pause the printring loop, The printer gives an error, the printer does not take the page , or i need to go away from home. i never had a perfect print without interuptions. regarding the data in the thread i cannot check if a button was pressed? and thank you i am really glad to hear that my code looks good. i am sealf learnimng.

Comment: @StoicaVasile - Pausing the thread seems the wrong way to do this. You should focus on printing a page at a time. Break the task down into smaller parts. You cannot access any UI controls in a non-UI thread, but you can pass a boolean value in as a parameter that you create while still in the UI thread. You don't pass in a control, you pass in the `bool`.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking implies that you want to use the [`Thread.Suspend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.suspend) and [`Thread.Resume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.resume) methods. Possibly like this:

```
private volatile Thread _printThread;

private async void DGW6BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Work.Printer_ Print = new Work.Printer_();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _printThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        try
        {
            Print.Print_File(this, dataGridView6, StatusText, progressBar1,
                variablesStatus);
        }
        finally { _printThread = null; }
    });
}

public void BTN6PPauza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var printThread = _printThread;
    if (printThread != null)
    {
        if (printThread.ThreadState.HasFlag(ThreadState.Running))
        {
            printThread.Suspend();
        }
        else if (printThread.ThreadState.HasFlag(ThreadState.Suspended))
        {
            printThread.Resume();
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation of these two methods includes several cautionary warnings that discourage usage:

> `Thread.Suspend` has been deprecated. Use other classes in `System.Threading`, such as `Monitor`, `Mutex`, `Event`, and `Semaphore`, to synchronize Threads or protect resources.

> Do not use the `Suspend` and `Resume` methods to synchronize the activities of threads. You have no way of knowing what code a thread is executing when you suspend it. If you suspend a thread while it holds locks during a security permission evaluation, other threads in the `AppDomain` might be blocked. If you suspend a thread while it is executing a class constructor, other threads in the `AppDomain` that attempt to use that class are blocked. Deadlocks can occur very easily.

It's up to you if you want to accept these risks. If you ask me, you shouldn't.

---

**Note:** The `Suspend` and `Resume` methods are not supported on .NET Core and later platforms. On these platforms they throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception. You can use them only if you target the .NET Framework platform.

Comment: The OP is accessing controls from the non-UI thread. You might want to mention the issues there too.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think that the OP will be satisfied if their application is barely working most of the time. At least my answer was written under this assumption. In case I am wrong, and the OP's intentions is to write a state of the art application, this answer will be completely useless and I will have to delete it.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, previously i had tried printThread.Suspend(); but it gives me **System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Thread suspend is not supported on this platform.'**

Comment: @StoicaVasile you are right. I just noticed the documentation: *"**Exceptions:** `PlatformNotSupportedException` .NET Core and .NET 5+ only: In all cases."* I missed it because it's not as prominent as it is in the documentation of the [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) method. You can guess that personally I have never used the `Suspend`/`Resume` methods. 

Comment: @StoicaVasile you could consider migrating to the .NET Framework, where these methods are still supported.

Answer (score -1):

i made this work, i do not know if it is the right way but for the moment it works

```
public partial class Program_Form : Form
{
    readonly BackgroundWorker m_oWorker;
    CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = null;

    [STAThread]
    private void Program_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // long code here 
    }

    private async void DGW6BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = _tokenSource.Token;


            Work.Printer_ Print = new Work.Printer_();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                    Print.Print_File(this, dataGridView6, StatusText, progressBar1, token);
            });
    }

    public void BTN6PPauza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Referenced class:

```
namespace OfficeTools.Work
{
    class Printer_
    {
         public void Print_File(Program_Form callForm, DataGridView DGW, TextBox Status, ProgressBar Progress, CancellationToken Token)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in DGW.Rows)
            {
                file = DGW.Rows[Row.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                PrintFiles.Print_Word(file);

               if (Token.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                  try
                  {
                    Winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                    winword = null;
                   }
                  catch { }
                  return;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kind regards all

Comment: Nice, but this is not an answer to the question that you asked. The question is how to start / stop a thread, not how to cancel a method.

Comment: yes you are right, but i made a shortcut, on the datagrid with the files i had added another column with the status (printed or not) if i stop the printer wil remember wher i stopped. when i start the thread again will skip the printed files. and continue where i stopped. if i whant to print again all the files i added a button to change the status from printed to not printed :( but i will keep digging maybe i will find a better solution